# How to create index when there is a arithmetic operation done on that column

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a query that selects records from a table that are older than 72 days.

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TIMESTAMP <= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '72' HOUR;
```

The performance of this query is horrible, so I have added an index to the TIMESTAMP column.

This works fine with *thousands* of records, but when the record count is *10 million* (even more, sometimes), I hardly see any performance improvement with the index.

My guess is that the arithmetic operation is killing the performance of the query.

Please tell me if there are any other approaches to speeding up this query.

Comment: Not necessarily.   Please show your explain plan along with auto trace output.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Currently I don't have access to the box where I have tested. I have seen the access is taking the maximum time of the query. The cost with and without the index are almost same.

Comment: Then come back when you have data to show.

Comment: How selective are you being? What proportion of your records are more than 72 hours old? An index won't help unless you are getting looking for a fairly small subset of your data.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Currently I have 144 hours data. It is more than 50%.

Comment: I think you meant to say "72 *hours*". And, as Alex says, since your predicate matches more than 50% of the records in the database, you most probably *don't* want the index to be used.

Comment: However, a covering index over (TIMESTAMP, ID) *may* improve the performance (as long as you have also taken care of the potential issue highlighted by mrks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the timestamp column is of the type `TIMESTAMP`, the problem is that the implicit conversion from `DATE` (which is returned by `SYSDATE`) to `TIMESTAMP` kills the index.

You could add a function-based index or you could change the use of `SYSDATE` to `SYSTIMESTAMP`.

Comment: The TIMESTAMP analogue of `SYSDATE` is `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ... `LOCALTIMESTAMP` will (probably) work, but includes time zone information.

Comment: @mrks: Used a function based index and it shows some improvement.